# how use checkbox that show in control panel program feature

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2008, checkbox

I am making a windows application in C#.

I want to use the checkbox that comes in windows 7 control panel program feature.

- If the subcheckboxes of the tree are all not selected then the parent checkbox should be filled
- If all subitems are selected then the parent checkbox should be checked
- If all subitems are unselected then the parent checkbox should be unselected.

I am using separate checkboxes (like `checkboxImageList`, found in google), not a `treeview` checkbox.

Comment: It seems that you want to simulate a `treeView` by using `checkBox`. Why not using a `treeView` instead?

Answer (score 0):

Well, a treeview checkbox would save you a lot of hassle here, because you can just use LINQ to check or uncheck all nodes when a node is clicked by handling the Click event (let's say `clickedItem` is the node that was clicked:

```
foreach (TreeNode node in clickedItem.Nodes.ToList())
{
    node.IsSelected = clickedItem.IsSelected;
}
```

Also, from a user interface point of view, the `TreeView` makes sense. If you absolutely insist on using individual checkboxes, then you just build a tree of `CheckBox` items in memory, perhaps using something like this sample [`Tree<T>` data type](http://dvanderboom.wordpress.com/2008/03/15/treet-implementing-a-non-binary-tree-in-c/), and then when you click on a checkbox, just recursively travel through the tree until you've checked every box under that one.

But consider what will happen with your app. You might have so many options in the future that you'll need a way to programatically add them. You might need scrolling. You might need to make the entire thing configurable. And once you've added all that, you'll just have re-implemented `TreeView`.

Comment: checkbox has a property

 Threestate=True;

By using this we use three state in checkbox(selected,unselected,intermediate)

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not entirely sure how that information relates to my answer. Is there something in my answer you do not understand or would like me to improve upon?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should better use a `TreeView`. [Here's](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/tree/Tri-State_Tree_View.aspx) an example of a `TreeView` managing alone the mid-check state.

Comment: checkbox has a property

 Threestate=True;

By using this we use three state in checkbox(selected,unselected,intermediate)